# How to execute a command in many servers at the same time

Tags: python, fabric, python-multithreading

I have a function that takes 30 seconds to complete.

```
def reload():
    sudo("service apache2 reload")
```

This function have to be run on 400 servers simultaneously. As I need to complete this step as quickly as possible, I don't want to execute serially.  What method can be used to do this?

Comment: Could you reformulate your question so that we can better understand what you exactly want? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

you can use "fabric" a python Library

install fabric:

```
$ pip install fabric
```

See http://www.fabfile.org/

sample fab script:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['host1', 'host2',...,'host400'] 

@parallel
def reload():
    sudo("service apache2 reload")
```

and execute it on a set of 400 servers, in parallel, like so:

```
$ fab -H -P reload
```

for better configuration check fabric [docs.](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12/usage/parallel.html)